# wordpress resizing image

Tags: php, wordpress, image-resizing

I use plugin wp-type, there I can make costum pages, this plugin have function to display image in page or post, but fom me this function not work, image was still not resized. Maybe are some better solution to resize proportionaly images in pages/posts ?

```
<?php echo(types_render_field("product_image", array("alt"=>"Product image",
"width"=>"300","height"=>"200","proportional"=>"true"))); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this plugin to achieve your requirement, I have used in many of my projects and it worked perfectly. Here is the plugin link http://austinmatzko.com/wordpress-plugins/filosofo-custom-image-sizes/

Comment: Pplease help me with this plugin I try place in theme `wp_get_attachment_image(" 
http://localhost/doctor/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/058.jpg ", '300x400');?>` but this not work ;(

Comment: can you explain what you have tried.. and what kind of problem you are facing?

Comment: I use http://austinmatzko.com/wordpress-plugins/filosofo-custom-image-sizes/ plugin ant try resize image in page, but `wp_get_attachment_image` function not work image wasn't be displayed

Comment: please post your code what are you using, else it would be difficult to point out what is the issue. As I have used this and it works greatly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use [add_image_size](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size) in the functions.php file for your theme. This will allow you to set the image size you want (assuming you want to use this size a bunch in your theme). You will also need to use a regenerate thumbnails plugin such as [this one](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) to recreate the various image sizes.